# Django generic UpdateView: Getting the object to be updated

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm actually using the `django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView` to update a models specific fields. Since I'm not passing the primary key or slug of the object to be updated, I'm simply overriding the `get_object` method:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return Model.objects.get(user__id=self.request.user.id)
```

If there is no object found at `get_object` I'm receiving a 'Query does not match[...]' error, which is totally fine. But in case of an exception I'd like to redirect the user instead of showing the exception output. Unfortunately the `get_object` method forbids redirects as django expects it to return an object.

Is there any elegant way to check if the requested object exists and if not to redirect the user? I'd also like to avoid overriding the `dispatch` method to perform the check for object existence there. This would lead to an further unnecessary database query. So I'd had three queries for a simple update view.

Any advice would be really great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the `get` in your `get_object` method, allow a DoesNotExist error to propagate (don't catch it), and override the dispatch method and catch the DoesNotExist exception there. From dispatch, you can return a redirect.

Something like:

```
def dispatch(...):
    try:
         return super(...)  # call superclass dispatch
    except Model.DoesNotExist:
         return ... your redirection ...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing right now, but if the object is existing and therefore no error is thrown, this would lead to querying the database twice, once in `dispatch` and then once again in `get_object`.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you query in `dispatch`, though. Dispatch calls the stuff that calls `get_object`. Raise the error in `get_object` and let `dispatch` solely handle the catching of the exception.

Comment: (add pseudocode skeleton to answer; hopefully, this makes it more clear)

Comment: Oh, my mistake - forgot to return. Thanks for helping out, cheers :)